# Volley throw 502 bad gateway

Tags: android, android-volley, http-get

I'm using Volley to send Get method.Sometimes  I have  502 bad gateway server error.I don't know what is a wrong or how i can solve my problem

This is a source code

```
    public void polygonRequest(final String userID, final String secretKey) {
    showpDialog("loading");
    polygonModelList.clear();

    String url = ServerUtil.polygon+userID+"/"+secretKey;
    final JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    SavedPolygonJson polygonModel=new SavedPolygonJson();
                    polygonModel.setPolygonJson(response.toString());
                    polygonModel.saveInStorage();
                    parsePolygonRequest(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    hidepDialog();
                    showOneItemDialog(error.toString(),false);

                }
            });


    jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            10000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    CoreApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

When I send my request with browser i have not any errors.How i can fixed this error...
How i can combine browser's request header with Volley request header?
thanks

Comment: Cannot comment so posting here. Mostly this happens when total time of response is greater than the volley retry time

Answer (score 0):

Increase the  the read time out session if you are using the retrofit.
  Or in case of volley in crease the request time session  from its default

for cross check hit the url directly in web browser and calculate the time  that how much time it takes to fetch the response according to that you set the  request session time

This happens because if your network lib does not get the  response on predefined request time  it show  bad gateway 502